# удаление слова из файла, си

Tags: c

Пишу программу, которая бы удаляла введенное с клавиатуры слово из текстового файла(если оно там имеется). После запуска, оставшиеся слова в файле btest.txt становятся одной большой строкой. Как можно сделать так, чтобы в выходном файле слова были расположены так же как и во входном, только без уже удаленного слова?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char buf[512];
    char word[128];

    FILE *in_file = fopen("C:\\atest.txt", "r");
    FILE *out_file = fopen("C:\\btest.txt", "w");

    if(!in_file || !out_file)
        return -1;

    printf("Input word: ");
    scanf("%127s", word);

    while(!feof(in_file))
    {
        fscanf(in_file, "%511s", buf);
        if(!strcmp(buf, word) )
            continue;
        fprintf(out_file, "%s", buf);
    }
    fclose(in_file);
    fclose(out_file);
}
```

Comment: Если у вас слова по одному в строке - то просто записывайте их как `fprintf(out_file, "%s\n", buf);`. И еще учтите, что `feof(in_file)` срабатывает не перед, а *после* неудачной попытки читать за концом файла.

Comment: `strstr()`, во-первых, во-вторых, не понятно какой(-ие) у вас разделители могут быть между "словами". И в-третьих, ну какой `scanf()`?!